# Toggling google maps markers without jQuery

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API v.3 to display markers of locations and info about locations from an XML file that is constructed upon page loading from an MySQL database (mysql -> xml -> Google Maps API).

What I need to know is how to toggle on/off markers depending on whether the id of my checkboxes match the value of the variable defined on the line

```
var nom = markers[i].getAttribute("nom");
```

using only plain javascript and NOT jQuery. Here is the full script I am using:

```
//main function
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(15.31,32.35),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

//calls a php script that builds the xml file from the database and prepares the map -- see below in the question
downloadUrl("phpToXML.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var nom = markers[i].getAttribute("nom");
      var lieu = markers[i].getAttribute("lieu");
      var date = markers[i].getAttribute("date");
      var dateFin = markers[i].getAttribute("dateFin");
      var descCas = markers[i].getAttribute("descCas");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<strong>"  + nom + " > " + lieu + "</strong><br />" + date + " - " + dateFin + "<p>" + descCas + "</p>";
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

I suppose I have to create an array to store the markers and use a function inside a loop to run through all markers and change the visibility value of just the instances associated with a value of the variable NOM that matches the id of the checkbox. The problem is simply that I do not know how to do this.

To wrap this up, here the basic structure of the HTML

```
<div id="selecteur">
<form id="selection" action="#">
<li><input type="checkbox" name="entreprises" id="NAME#1 SOME JS FUNCTION HAS TO BE CALLED HERE I GUESS></li>           
</form>
</div>
```

and the XML output is typically like:

```
<markers>
  <marker nom="Nestl&#xE9;" lieu="Colombie" date="1986" dateFin="2012" lat="4.115673" lng="-72.930130" type="victHu" victNHu="0" descCas="&lt;p&gt;Entre 1986 et 2009, 13 syndicalistes sont assassin&amp;eacute;s, dont, en 2009, Gustavo Gomez, suite &amp;agrave; une p&amp;eacute;tition du syndicat contre Nestl&amp;eacute; Purina Colombie et en 2007 Jos&amp;eacute; de Jesus Marin Vargas. De m&amp;ecirc;me en 2005, Gustavo Romero, de Nestl&amp;eacute; Cicolac, est assassin&amp;eacute; apr&amp;egrave;s avoir d&amp;eacute;couvert que Nestl&amp;eacute; utilise du lait p&amp;eacute;rim&amp;eacute; pour produire son fameux produit Milo.&lt;/p&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;hr /&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;p&gt;Nestl&amp;eacute; rejette toutes les accusations d'intimidation et de tout comportement anti-syndical. Il reviendrait aux filiales et aux autorit&amp;eacute;s locales de r&amp;eacute;soudre les questions de s&amp;eacute;curit&amp;eacute; et de conflit.&lt;/p&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;hr /&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;p&gt;Sources:&lt;/p&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;ul&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;li&gt;ALLIANCE SUD (2011)&lt;/li&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;li&gt;MULTIWATCH (2011)&lt;/li&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;li&gt;MULTIWATCH(2007)&lt;/li&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;li&gt;ILRF (2006)&lt;/li&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;li&gt;MULTIWATCH (2012b)&lt;/li&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;li&gt;MULTIWATCH (2012)&lt;/li&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;/ul&gt;"/>
  <marker nom="Nestl&#xE9;" lieu="Suisse" date="2003" dateFin="2008" lat="46.480400" lng="8.133600" type="victHu" victNHu="0" descCas="&lt;p&gt;Deux cas d'infiltration et d'espionnage du groupe altermondialiste Attac qui menait une enqu&amp;ecirc;te sur Nestl&amp;eacute; afin de publier un livre sur l'entreprise.&lt;/p&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;hr /&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;p&gt;L'organisation Attac, selon Peter Brabeck-Letmathe (PDG de Nestl&amp;eacute; entre 1997 et 2008), se montre violente et repr&amp;eacute;sente donc une menace r&amp;eacute;elle pour Nestl&amp;eacute;. La d&amp;eacute;marche n'avait, selon lui, rien d'illicite et fut men&amp;eacute;e &amp;agrave; titre pr&amp;eacute;ventif contre la menace potentielle d'une guerre id&amp;eacute;ologique men&amp;eacute;e par Attac contre Nestl&amp;eacute;.&lt;/p&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;hr /&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;p&gt;Sources:&lt;/p&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;ul&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;li&gt;ATTAC (2012)&lt;/li&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;li&gt;MULTIWATCH (2010d)&lt;/li&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;/ul&gt;"/>
  <!-- ... --?
</markers>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Toggle Google Maps markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966009/toggle-google-maps-markers)

Comment: it's no duplicate. read.

Comment: Read what?  You have answered your own question: create an array to store the markers and use a function inside a loop to run through all markers and change the visibility value of just the instances associated with a value of the variable NOM that matches the id of the checkbox.  That question is an example of how to do that.

Comment: so where in my code should I put the function that does that?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including a sample of any HTML/XML or CSS required for it to work.

Comment: thank you for your help, geocodezip. I edited as you suggested.

Comment: I don't see any sample XML to use for testing.

Comment: ok done -- hope it helps.

Comment: Complete XML that can be used with your page.

Comment: it's going to be extremely messy if I add the whole XML directly to the post. But you can check it out here: http://ethometrics.proethica.ch/carte/phpToXML.php

Comment: I get a javascript error in the [posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/qwmLhr46/), `Uncaught ReferenceError: customIcons is not defined`.  You didn't provide a **complete** example.

Comment: then please consider the original page -- the whole javascript is in the source: http://ethometrics.proethica.ch/carte

Comment: Looking at your code, I think you want something like [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put all your markers in an array (I named it `gmarkers`)
2. add the "nom" attribute as a property of the marker (gmarkers[i].nom), change:

   ```
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       position: point,
       icon: icon.icon
     });
   ```

To:

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        nom: nom,
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
    });
```

3. create a function to run onclick of a check box, that displays or hides the markers appropriately:

```
function displayNom(nom, checkbox) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); //or document.forms[0].elements;
    var cbs = []; //will contain all checkboxes
    var checkboxes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            cbs.push(inputs[i]);
            checkboxes[nodeValue(inputs[i].parentNode).trim()] = inputs[i];
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[gmarkers[i].nom].checked) {
            if (gmarkers[i].getMap() === null) gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
        } else {
            if (gmarkers[i].getMap() != null) gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
}
```

html to call the above:

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="entreprises" id="NAME#1" onclick="displayNom('Nestl&#xE9;', this)" />Nestl&#xE9;</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="entreprises" id="NAME#2" onclick="displayNom('Novartis', this)" />Novartis</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="entreprises" id="NAME#2" onclick="displayNom('Vitol', this)" />Vitol</li>
<!-- etc. -->
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwmLhr46/4/)
(too much code for a "code snippet")

Comment: Thanks a lot for the amazing job! Last issue is that I get "TypeError: checkboxes[gmarkers[i].nom] is undefined" upon ticking/unticking the checkboxes. (I applied your code to my web page at http://ethometrics.proethica.ch/carte)

Comment: Your code/ page is not the same as the sample posted.  Your change made it not work (the `<li>` text is empty) .  Fixing that is another question.

Comment: Really? I've edited out the differences in the scope of 3 sample <li></li> tags -- adding the corresponding name -- and I am still getting this error.

Comment: There is definitely an issue with how the nodeValue function work on my page. But I don't quite understand the details of this function, so it's not going to be easy for me to fix it.

Comment: It is not the nodeValue function. It is the displayNom function when there is no text content in the `<li>` (all nodeValue does is get that content).

Comment: but then why do I still get the error for <li> tags that DO HAVE text content? (see modified example)

Comment: Last I looked there were still nodes with no text content.  Look at the `checkboxes` array in a debugger.

Comment: all nodes should have text content now, and still this error.

Comment: Looks to me like some of the markers don't have "nom" attributes or the "nom" attributes don't match that text.  Your requirements are not well specified in your question.

Comment: I really don't get it. The xml file looks ok to me (all markers have "nom" attribute). I cannot see any substantive difference between my script and your fidle script -- which does exactly what I need. The only thing is that my checkboxes come checked but this is hardly relevant.

Comment: Ah ha! you are missing the custom "nom" property of the marker. Updated answer.

Comment: OMG! now unticking does hide, but ticking again does not set to visible.

Comment: That is a symptom of your "map" variable not being in the global scope.

Comment: Dear Sir, God sent you. I swear I will study javascript interactions with DOM before posting any question on this web site. Thank you for you patience and pedagogy. Have a beautiful day!